# How to squash all the contents of a multi-line file onto one line?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have a file with many thousands (possibly even millions) of lines, however I need all of the contents to be on one line and all spaces removed (there shouldn't be any spaces there, but there might be, and if there are, they should be removed). How can this be achieved?

To give some context, I got the `base64` output for a huge file and now need to pipe it into another command, however I need to pipe it in as one huge number, but as the file is made of multiple lines as opposed to having it all on one line, I am unable to pipe it into the program because it will treat every line as a new number and I need the whole thing to be treated as one big one.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, I hope that this can be achieved with a simple command and/or script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simpler way: use `tr`.

```
tr -d '[[:space:]]' <file1 >file2
```

(Use `sponge` if you need to write to the same file.)

---

Pretty easy with Vim:

```
vim -Nesc '%s/\_s//g' +wq file
```

- `-Nes` starts [silent](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#-s-ex), [non-compatible](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#-N) [ex-mode](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#-e) (for easy scripting with Vim).
- [`-c` and `+`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#-c) are used to run commands
- `%s/\_//g` [substitutes](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3As) in [all lines](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3A%25) all [whitespace](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cs), along with [any newlines](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C_), with nothing.
- `wq` saves the file and exits Vim.

---

With `awk`, set `RS` (record separator) to whitespace and `ORS` (output record separator) to nothing:

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]' -v ORS= '1' foo
```

With GNU awk, you can do in-place editing using `gawk -i inplace`.

Comment: This would be useful on a less big file... This file is so large that opening it in vim just crashes my machine and uses up all the RAM... And takes an incredibly long time to open...

Comment: @ParanoidPanda How large is so large?

Comment: It's 14.4GB in size.

Answer (score 4):

Pipe it through this perl regex:

```
perl -p -e 's/[\n\r ]*//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

AWK can do that by looping all the fields and using `printf "%s"`. Example

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s",$i}'
```

Sample run:

```
$ printf "to be or not to be\nthat is the question" | \         
> awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s",$i}'
tobeornottobethatisthequestion
```